# How build vlc project in the Xcode by xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, macos, vlc

I found Xcode project in the vlc sources (vlc/extras/package/macosx/vlc.xcodeproj) and want to build it in Xcode application.
I read this description https://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile/ , but in this one they build vlc by command line :(
Do next steps:

1. `xcrun clang` -> clang: error: no input files
2. `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select` -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer  -> ask password and complete
3. export CC="xcrun clang"
   export CXX="xcrun clang++"
   export OBJC="xcrun clang"
4. `git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc.git`
5. Open the vlc.xcodeproj (vlc/extras/package/macosx/vlc.xcodeproj) in the Xcode app and press `Product-Build`.

   After that build error occurs:
   **Schell Script Invocation error
   error: can't change directory to '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vlc-dsmzoapoknxsuwelsoqxjmdnotun/Build/Products' (No such file or directory)**

Really directory **/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vlc-dsmzoapoknxsuwelsoqxjmdnotun/Build/Products** not exists, but Xcode create this one then open project **/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vlc-dsmzoapoknxsuwelsoqxjmdnotun/Build**

What I do wrong?

What can I do to build vlc.xcodeproj in the Xcode app?

OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5

Xcode version Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Answer (score 1):

I have been contributing in VLC for a while. And I just got to know that the Xcode Project for VLC is called `Pseudo-VLC` because it is not supposed to be compiled/ran from Xcode.

For compilation or running, you would have to follow the terminal approach.

The Xcode Project for VLC exists, so that you can edit GUI